# Is it possible to programmatically create a Google form with images added to multiple short answer type questions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I need to create a quiz with Google forms that has several short answer questions (25) which include images. I tried to make powerpoint slides with the questions along with the images and was planning to add a jpeg of each slide to a short answer question.
I am familiar with using Google Apps Scriot to create forms with multiple choice and text answer questions but I do not know how to add images to the questions via this method
Is there a way to programmatically add these images instead of manually uploading an image to each question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It is only possible to add image items to the form, see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/image-item), but unfortunately NOT to a question

There is a already [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36765518)  filed on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). I recommend you to give it a "star" to indicate Google the importance of the feature.

Comment: You forgot to put a link to the issue...